# If statement on dropDownList listItem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add a condition to a DropDownList where a method can be executed by button click only if the user has selected a value different than the listItem (default value).

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" 
     DataTextField="proj_name" DataValueField="proj_name">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select a project to clone" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

How can I structure an if condition to validate that the selected value is not the ListItem (default value)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use asp.net delivered validation controls

Ex:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="rfv1"
                    ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"
                    Display="Static"
                    ErrorMessage="* Select a value"
                    InitialValue="DefaultValueHere"
                    runat="server"
                    ValidationGroup="V1"/>
```

Then edit your button markup to use ValidationGroup

```
<asp:Button Id="button1" ValidationGroup="V1" .../>
```

In your codebehind button click code add this

```
protected void button1_onlick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     If(Page.IsValid)
     {

       // your existing code here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See sample code below

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectValue == "")
{
// Write your code here
}
```

you can also have:

```
if (DropDownList1.Text == "Select a project to clone")
{
// Write your code here
}
```

Comment: @FeliceM I dont understand your comment "The check shall be on listItem".  Are you asking about DropDownList1.SelectedItem?

Comment: Malkassem, your code does not work because the value I am a checking is basically the default value appearing in the control when a value is not selected and the selectable values are bind to a datasource. However thanks for the support.